# setInterval() variable change error

Tags: javascript

The problem is when i use this function the first time it's work fine(the interval time is good), the second time too, but the third time it's doesn't work because the timer is the timer of the second time, but the variable Timer has changed.

Hoping that someone knows how to fix it.

```
function SetTimer()
{

    clearInterval(AutoMsgTimer);

    Timer = prompt("[AutoMsg] Timer de l'auto-messages en secondes :");

    TimerSec = Timer;
    Timer = Timer*1000;

    var AutoMsgTimer = setInterval(

        function AutoMsg()
        {
            if(AutoMsgStatus == true)
            {
                API.sendChat("/me " + AutoMsgText);
            }
        }

    , Timer);

}
```

Sorry for my english i'm french.

Comment: How/when are you using the SetTimer() function?

Comment: I use the SetTimer() here(in a console):                                                          else if(e == "/settimer")
 {
  SetTimer();
  API.chatLog("[AutoMsg] Le timer a été changé, c'est maintenant: " + TimerSec + " secondes.");
 }

Comment: My variable are reported like this: var Timer;
var TimerSec;

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead of redeclaring your variable everytime you call `SetTimer()`

```
var AutoMsgTimer = SetTimer();  //Make sure you call the SetTimer this way, store the return value...

function SetTimer() {
  if (AutoMsgTimer ){
    clearInterval(AutoMsgTimer);
  }
  Timer = prompt("[AutoMsg] Timer de l'auto-messages en secondes :");
  TimerSec = Timer;
  Timer = Timer*1000;
  var interval = setInterval(
    function()   {
      if(AutoMsgStatus == true)
      {
        API.sendChat("/me " + AutoMsgText);
      }
  }, Timer);
 return interval;
}
```